# HTML5 button type=reset stopped working

Tags: html

I just modified the markup of my page, I added a couple of div's to wrap each field so I can play the layoot dynamically and now the reset stopped working and I don't see why

```
 <div id="form-area" data-active="">
      <div id="form-first-line">
           <form role="form">
                <div class="fild-group to-hide">
                     <select id="form-job-state">
                          <option value="any" selected>Job State</option>
                          <option value="any" >Any</option>
                          <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                          <option value="Queued">Queued</option>
                          <option value="Running">Running</option>
                     </select>
                </div>
                <div class="fild-group to-hide">
                     <select id="form-no-symbols">
                          <option value="" selected>Number of slots</option>
                          <option value="$gt" >&gt;</option>
                          <option value="$lt">&lt;</option>
                          <option value="$in">=</option>
                          <option value="$lte">&lt;=</option>
                          <option value="$gte">&gt;=</option>
                          <option value="$ne">&lt;&gt;</option>
                     </select>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-no-slots" value="0">
                </div>
                <div class="fild-group">
                     <label for="form-start-date">Start Date</label>
                     <div class="clean"></div>
                     <input type="date" class="form-control" id="form-start-date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">
                     <input type="time" class="form-control" id="form-start-time" placeholder="HH:MM" value="00:00">
                </div>
                <div class="fild-group">
                     <label for="form-end-date">End Date</label>
                     <div class="clean"></div>
                     <input type="date" class="form-control" id="form-end-date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">
                     <input type="time" class="form-control" id="form-end-time" placeholder="HH:MM" value="23:59">
                </div>
           </form>
      </div>
      <div id="form-second-line">
           <button id="form-query" data-type="" type="button" disabled>Query</button>
           <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
      </div>
 </div>
```

this is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juanpa/34k0nz42/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap it in a `<form>` 
Put `<form>` at line 1
and `</form>` at the very end.

Instead of adding a `</form>`, just move your already existing one a few lines deeper,
so it includes the buttons as well.

Also, you can change  into

```
<input type="reset" name="reset">
```

Answer (score 3):

Because your button is outside of the form you need to use the new `form` attribute on your button. [This site](http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-form-attribute/) gives more information about the `form` attribute.

See http://jsfiddle.net/34k0nz42/1/.

1. Give your form an ID, `<form id='formId'>`
2. Use `form='formID` on your button, `<input form='formID' />`.